Is there a way to retrieve Stripe custom account by metadata or email?
I have stripe custom connect accounts that have spefici metadata, how do I retrieve said account using the metaData or email?
const getAccount = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(
  {
  expand: {
    email: "eg@gmail.com",
  },
});

the above returns an invalid array error.

Stripe does not support something like this today. Their List APIs do not have a metadata filter at all as it wouldn't scale. They do have a separate Search API that does support filtering by metadata but it's only available for a small number of resources and the Account one is not one of those.
I'm afraid the best solution is to cache that information locally in your own database instead. If you can't, you might have to use the List Accounts API and then paginate to find the one with the right metadata key/value.

Thank you. You are right, I just stored the account id on my db. Listing the account and filtering through it doesn't work, since the max amount of accounts you can get back is 100.
